# ASP.NET Core NodeServices on Azure Linux WebApp

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, nodeservices

I am used to publish Azure WebApps on Windows but now I am trying to deploy an ASP.NET Core 3 (with NodeServices) to a Linux WebApp and I am receiving the following error message:

`InvalidOperationException: Failed to start Node process. To resolve this:.`

[1] Ensure that Node.js is installed and can be found in one of the PATH directories.
Current PATH enviroment variable is: /opt/dotnetcore-tools:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/home/site/wwwroot
Make sure the Node executable is in one of those directories, or update your PATH.

On Windows WebApps I have a lot of other apps and all are fine.

On Kudu I typed `node -v` and the output was `v12.13.0`.

Can anybody please help me?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you found a solution?

Comment: @Ricardo Did you solve it? I am facing same problem

Comment: Yes, I did... but it requires extra config... can you please wait a few days? I will write an article explaining it...

Comment: It is answered @PhaniKrishnaVemireddy.

Comment: You can check @GuilhermeMeinlschmiedtAbdo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a long research and the assistance of Microsoft's Engineer https://github.com/caroe2014 this is the three steps final answer:

1) Startup.cs

```
    services.AddNodeServices(options =>
        {
          if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux))
          {
            options.ProjectPath = Path.GetFullPath("/home/site/wwwroot");
          }
        }
      );
```

2) And what I found is Node is not present in the container so it is necessary to have a script to install and start it before starting the app itself. So I have this **start1.cs** file:

```
#!/bin/bash

apt-get install curl
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash
apt-get install -y nodejs

set -e
export PORT=8080
export ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:$PORT
dotnet "Web.Identity.dll"
```

Where Web.Identity.dll is the dll of my app.

3) Set startup command to **/home/site/wwwroot/start1.sh** (On Azure Portal - App service Configuration - or Azure DevOps).

That's all.

Comment: Thank you, @Ricardo . In fact, I tried the above approach, but as post-deployment scripts.  I could install from SSH console, but when running from post-deployment scripts, it is throwing permission error. Will try this approach.

Comment: It worked for me... You can see the devops project here [link](https://dev.azure.com/ricardogaefke/Profile4D)

Answer (score 0):

Try to mention the path in the code, This is how NodeServices was configured in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddNodeServices(options =>
{
    options.ProjectPath = "Path\That\Doesnt\Exist";
});
```

Comment: I tried both `options.ProjectPath = "../../opt/nodejs/12.13.0";` and `options.ProjectPath = "opt/nodejs/12.13.0";`and got same error...

Comment: i guess you need to pass the full path, path where the files resides

Comment: I didn't get if I need to pass the path to package.json or to node folder... No success yet...